# How to process payments with service fee being deducted in Visa Cybersource Payments API?

Tags: api

I have an app that I would like to add payment processing similar to Amazon payment processing into it where sub-merchants get paid by customers with service fee being deducted, I can see in https://developer.visa.com/capabilities/cybersource/reference#cybersource__cybs_payments_v2__v2__process_a_payment the following request body but there is no field in request body to specify a service fee:

```
   {
"clientReferenceInformation": {
"code": "TC588171_3"
},
"processingInformation": {
"commerceIndicator": "internet"
},
"aggregatorInformation": {
"subMerchant": {
"cardAcceptorID": "1234567890",
"country": "US",
"phoneNumber": "650-432-0000",
"address1": "900 Metro Center",
"postalCode": "94404-2775",
"locality": "Foster City",
"name": "Visa Inc",
"administrativeArea": "CA",
"region": "PEN",
"email": "test@cybs.com"
},
"name": "V-Internatio",
"aggregatorID": "123456789"
},
"orderInformation": {
"billTo": {
"country": "US",
"lastName": "VDP",
"address2": "Address 2",
"address1": "201 S. Division St.",
"postalCode": "48104-2201",
"locality": "Ann Arbor",
"administrativeArea": "MI",
"firstName": "RTS",
"phoneNumber": "999999999",
"district": "MI",
"buildingNumber": "123",
"company": "Visa",
"email": "test@cybs.com"
},
"amountDetails": {
"totalAmount": "102.21",
"currency": "USD"
}
},
"paymentInformation": {
"card": {
"expirationYear": "2031",
"number": "5555555555554444",
"securityCode": "123",
"expirationMonth": "12",
"type": "002"
}
}
}
```

Is there a way or a workaround to get a service fee deducted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service fees go in the orderInformation block. Like this:

`"orderInformation": {
    "amountDetails": {
      "totalAmount": "102.21",
      "currency": "USD",
      "serviceFeeAmount": "3.00"
    },`

There are a few prerequisites to using service fees. One of which you must be using First Data as your processor. For more details check this [documentation](http://apps.cybersource.com/library/documentation/dev_guides/Service_Fees_SO_API/Service_Fees_SO_API.pdf).